# Не работает jquere код

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, node.js, bootstrap

Всем хай и у меня проблема . Я хотел сделать сайт на bootstrap и сервер на nodejs . Я не особо шарю в bootsrap и просто нашёл статью и работал по ней . В статье применяется jquere  но там нет его подключения . Иза этого выбивает в консоль вот такую ошибку `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. 
Подскажите как правильно его подключить . Я пытался по статьям но у меня ничего не вышло . Вот статья : https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-bootstrap-4-%D0%B7%D0%B0-30-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-d268d52d6c84 
И у меня иза этого не получилось поставить фон для шапки . Вот css :

```css
.navbar{ 
    background:#F97300;
}
.nav-link , .navbar-brand{ 
    color: #f4f4f4; cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-link{ 
    margin-right: 1em !important;
}
.nav-link:hover{ 
    background: #f4f4f4; color: #f97300; 
}
.navbar-collapse{  
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.navbar-toggler{  
    background:#fff !important;
}
.header{
    background-image: url('../img/headerback.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.79);
}
```

jquery код:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.header').height($(window).height());
})
```

js:

```js
const express     = require('express');
const app         = express();
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert      = require('assert'); 
const url         = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const pug         = require('pug');
const port        = 3000

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", "public");
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render("index")
})
app.get('/about', (req, res) =>{
    res.render("about")
})
app.get('/main.css', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile('css/main.css')
})
console.log(`Сервер запушен , порт ${port}`)

app.listen(port)
```

Comment: просто надо подключить jquery в html

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: я уже пытался . Сейчас приклиплю и html . Ивините но он в формате pug

Comment: тогда вот так : `script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js')`

Comment: я уже пробывал . Ноль реакции

Comment: может компиляция затупила ? перезапустите ..

Comment: неа . Тут проблема точно не в этом

Comment: ну подключите локально -

Answer (score 0):

Страница загрузки Jquery: https://jquery.com/download/
Открываешь ссылку нужной тебе версией, копируешь код, создаешь файл с оф.названием, вставляешь туда данный код, сохраняешь.
Там же есть инструкция, как установить посредством ноуда.

Comment: после скачивания нечего не изминилось